# Flash Modulus Glitch?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, modulus

This is driving me absolutely crazy! Why doesn't this work??? The if statement is never tripping, even when the trace clearly shows the damned number % 10 is equal to zero...

```
var starSpawnTime:int = 0;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
stop();

function update(e:Event): void {
starSpawnTime++;

trace(starSpawnTime);
trace("Modulus: " + starSpawnTime % 10);

if ((starSpawnTime % 10) == 0) {
    sStarBuffer = new SStar();
    sStarBuffer.x = 560;
    sStarBuffer.y = getRandomNumber(0, 400);
    stage.addChild(sStarBuffer);
    stars.push(sStarBuffer);
}
```

Comment: remove stage from stage.addChild

Comment: You can use `(starSpawnTime % 10).toString() == "0"` within `'if'`.

Comment: How do you *know* the if statement isn't "tripping"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the code (simplified) and it works

```
var starSpawnTime:int = 0;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
stop();

function update(e:Event): void {
    starSpawnTime++;

    trace(starSpawnTime);
    trace("Modulus: " + starSpawnTime % 10);

    if ((starSpawnTime % 10) == 0) {
        trace("BAM")
    }
}
```

chances are it's not the modulo operator that's causing the problems

Answer (score 0):

It may be misleading due to floating point rounding error. When using floating point numbers, you represent numbers approximately by keeping two multipliers and using their multiple to represent the number. This has an unfortunate limitation of not being able to represent all whole numbers, because, obviously, some whole numbers are primes, or cannot be represented as a multiple with sufficient precision.

By convention, numbers with very tiny fractional part are rounded before they are printed - this is why you see pretty output, but the values don't behave as expected.

Even if you operate on integers, Flash will internally convert them to floats, calculate and cast the result to expected type, so you don't have proper integer math in Flash.

What you can do in your case: since `starSpawnTime` is originally an integer, it looks like it won't do any harm if you did this:

```
if (!int(startSpawnTime % 10)) { . . . }
```

or

```
if (int(startSpawnTime % 10) == 0) { . . . }
```

If you were extremely concerned about performance, you could implement integer division yourself, or maybe use induction to calculate the reminder - but I would leave this as an exercise for the reader :)

As an aside: integers are not nullable in Flash, once declared, they are assigned the default value, the default value of an integer is `0`. So writing `var i:int = 0;` is redundant, `var i:int` is enough.